# TypeScript function passes type check when not expected to

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typing

I have a function `identityOrCall` that either calls the function given to it, or returns the value. `value` is a generic type.

```js
function identityOrCall <T>(value: T): T {
  if (typeof value === 'function')
    return value()
  else
    return value
}

identityOrCall(() => 'x') // -> 'x'
```

The line `identityOrCall(() => 'x')` appears to pass the compiler's type checking.

Why? Shouldn't it give an error?

If `identityOrCall` is passed a function, I would expect the generic type `T` to be set to `Function` and that `identityOrCall` should return a `Function` type.

Instead I'm able to pass a `Function` type as an argument and have `identityOrCall` return a `string` type.

Why is this? It appears inconsistent to me, but I must be missing something.

Comment: `identityOrCall(() => 'x')` will not return an error (why would it?) in this case `T` will be `() => string` which is a valid type

Comment: @apokryfos The misunderstanding I have is that I would expect `identityOrCall` to return the same type as it's argument. If given a `Function` type as an argument I would expect it to return a `Function` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, since the function return type is not noted anywhere, TypeScript takes its type to be `any`. `any` is not type-safe; it's assignable to anything. Here, TS extracts `T` from the `any` return value (since `any` can be narrowed down to T).

Best to avoid types of `any` whenever possible. I like using TSLint's [`no-unsafe-any`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unsafe-any/) which forbids this sort of thing.

For similar reasons, the following does not throw a TypeScript error (and is prohibited using the above linting rule), even though it's clearly unsafe:

```
declare const fn: () => any;
function identityOrCall<T>(value: T): T {
    return fn();
}

const result = identityOrCall(() => 'x') // -> 'x'
// result is typed as: () => 'x'. Huh?
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the corrrect explanation. I'm using `"noImplicitAny"` in my `tsconfig.json`.


This also appears to give no compilation errors: `identityOrCall(function (): string { return 'x' })`

Comment: Actually, I think I understand now. So the `T` assumes the "loosest" type here which is `any`, as opposed to immediately assuming the type of the first `T` typed argument.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have a method behave differently based on the parameters I think the easiest way is to specify [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

```js
function identityOrCall<T>(value: () => T): T;
function identityOrCall<T>(value: T): T;

function identityOrCall <T>(value: () => T|T): T {
  if (typeof value === 'function')
    return value()
  else
    return value
}

const result = identityOrCall(() => 'x') // first overload
const result2 = identityOrCall('x') // second overload

result.split(' ');  // No error
result2.split(' '); // No error
result(); // error not callable
```

When calling the method TS will resolve the signature by going through the overloads until it finds one which matches (meaning order of defining overloads matters here).

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPA8gJwGEBDAG1IB4AVAPgAoA3MkNALkToEpEBeGxKp3ZUA3AChQkWAmTpMMHARLlq9JqRbChA8ZOjwkqDFjxEypRKsbM2HbnwEAfQcMQBvMYmTAOOAA5ocD7qLLw8PIgA5HrSYJGcnl6I%20GhQIPhIIWhciWikAM5oiV4paRmIWWIAvmJiEAj5UMlo%20SCkTRFG8opm5HRcvPyRAB7xiAD044gAtEOjdQ1NKa3tAEy8ssYKpsqkdCNjkzNzkbXLbVAAdPl%20pAr7UZwiXkcAcnCIaPj4cPhi52trrd7pFHs83h8vj8-gCoFxwVMob9EGA4E0IOZiAAjUhoIA)